# Custom compare function for STL make_heap, pop_heap, how to make it work in graph search routine?

Tags: c++, lambda, heap, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

My intention is to implement Prim's algorithm to find the Minimum Spanning Tree of an undirected graph, using a heap as data structure hosting nodes not yet traversed.
I have set up a couple of classes `Edge` and `Node` so that a `Graph` is a `list<Node>`, and a `Node` is a `list<Edge>`:

```
    class Edge
    {
     public:
        Edge();
        Edge(int, int, int);

        std::array<int, 2> getNodes() const;
        int getCost() const;

        bool operator==(const Edge&) const;
        bool operator!=(const Edge&) const;

    private:
        int node1, node2;       // nodes are just indices of the nodes in the graph
        int cost;
   };
```

and

```
   class Node
   {
    public:
       Node();
       Node(const Edge edg);

       int getLabel() const;

       inline std::list<Edge>::iterator begin() {return edges.begin();}
       inline std::list<Edge>::iterator end() {return edges.end();}

       std::list<Edge>::iterator erase(int);

       bool operator==(Node&) const;
       bool operator!=(Node&) const;

   private:
       int label;
       std::list<Edge> edges;
};
```

I use `make_heap` and `pop_heap` in my Prim routine below, but my implementation does not work.
I suppose this is due to an incorrect implementation of the comparison function in the heap routines.
The cumbersome compare function I use is made up of nested lambdas, because there is the need to identify the nodes in the graph that have a crossing edge with the set of nodes already traversed:

```
    void heapPrim(Graph& graph)    // imported graph, all nodes inside
    {
        list<Node> X(1, graph[0]); // X hosts the traversed nodes
        vector<Node> unexplored_nodes( graph.begin(), graph.end() );

        // take away first traversed node from unexplored_nodes
        remove_if(unexplored_nodes.begin(), unexplored_nodes.end(), 
                  [X](const Node& a) mutable {return a == X.front();});
        unexplored_nodes.pop_back();

        // here lays the problem
        make_heap(unexplored_nodes.begin(), unexplored_nodes.end(),
            [X](Node& a, Node& b) mutable ->bool {
                int temp_score_a(INFTY), temp_score_b(INFTY);   // INFTY: costant = 10^8

                // comparison function applies only to nodes with crossing edges to X
                for (list<Node>::iterator iter = X.begin(); iter != X.end(); ++iter) 
                {
                     list<Edge>::iterator find_a = find_if((*iter).begin(), (*iter).end(),
                                 [a](Edge& i){return i.getNodes()[1] == a.getLabel();});
                     if ( find_a != (*iter).end() )
                         temp_score_a = min( temp_score_a, (*find_a).getCost() );

                     list<Edge>::iterator find_b = find_if((*iter).begin(), (*iter).end(),
                                 [b](Edge& i){return i.getNodes()[1] == b.getLabel();});
                     if ( find_b != (*iter).end() )
                         temp_score_b = min( temp_score_b, (*find_b).getCost() );     
                };

                return temp_score_a > temp_score_b;
        });

    // main loop finds all MST nodes
    while ( X.size() != graph.size() ) {
        list<Edge>::iterator iter_min_edge = X.back().begin();
        X.push_back( unexplored_nodes.front() );

        // same compare lambda function as 'make_heap' above
        pop_heap(unexplored_nodes.begin(), unexplored_nodes.end(),
            [X](Node& a, Node& b) mutable ->bool {
                int temp_score_a(INFTY), temp_score_b(INFTY);
                for (list<Node>::iterator iter = X.begin(); iter != X.end(); ++iter) 
                {
                    list<Edge>::iterator find_a = find_if((*iter).begin(), (*iter).end(),
                                [a](Edge& i){return i.getNodes()[1] == a.getLabel();});
                    if ( find_a != (*iter).end() )
                        temp_score_a = min( temp_score_a, (*find_a).getCost() );

                    list<Edge>::iterator find_b = find_if((*iter).begin(), (*iter).end(),
                                [b](Edge& i){return i.getNodes()[1] == b.getLabel();});
                    if ( find_b != (*iter).end() )
                        temp_score_b = min( temp_score_b, (*find_b).getCost() );
              };

              return temp_score_a > temp_score_b;
          });
          unexplored_nodes.pop_back();
     }

      cout << "evolution of new nodes X: ";
      for (list<Node>::iterator iter = X.begin(); iter != X.end(); ++iter)
          cout << (*iter).getLabel() << ";  ";
      cout << endl;
 }
```

This implementation leads to incorrect results, that is, less-than-optimal `Node`s get picked in the MST.

My question: how to implement a comparison function for heaps that does not evaluate the `min` over all the range, but chooses it only among `Node`s that have crossing edges? Is this solution, by the way, possible at all to code?

Comment: Unrelated. There is no need to mark members defined inside the class with `inline`. There are implicitly `inline`.

Comment: Iterating within the comparison function is... let me put it this way... not how things are usually done. The function should compare two numbers and return. Precompute the score for each vertex and update as needed.

Comment: Since your ordering depends on `X`, you're effectively using a different function for each `pop_heap`, none of them equivalent to the function you used for `make_heap`. I doubt that the behaviour of that is well defined.